# What are the side effects of breaking the prototype chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript

We write a lot of JavaScript code to run our automated testing using a tool called TestComplete.  In several cases I've set up inheritance trees using the following syntax:

```js
function Parent()
{
    ...
    //some inline code here executes on object creation
}

Child.prototype = Parent;
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
function Child()
{
    Parent.call(this);
    ...
}
```

The reason I've used

```
Child.prototype = Parent;
```

instead of

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

is because there is code that is executed on the creation of a new object in the parent in some cases.  Setting the prototype this way has never been an issue, in that I've always been able to call all the functions defined in the Parent after having created a Child.

I suspect, however, I've actually broken the prototype chain in doing this and I've been saved by the fact that all the methods we define are defined inline (ie. inside the constructor function) and not using the object.prototype.method = ... syntax, and so the fact the chain is broken has gone unnoticed.

So I have two questions; have I broken the chain, and what are the side effects of breaking the prototype chain in JavaScript?

Comment: AFAIK you can't *break* the prototype chain because everything will inherit from Object anyway, which means there is always a chain back to Object. Could you clarify what you mean by breaking the chain?

Comment: Sure.  Check out this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ZCT4M/.  You'll notice that only the first alert is displayed.  If you change it to use new Parent() instead, all three alerts will display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "break" the prototype chain like this, you cannot access `Parent.prototype.*` methods and properties in `Child` instances and the `instanceof` operator does not work (`new Child() instanceof Parent === false`).

I understand why you don't want to use the `new` keyword for the inheritance. There is, however, a little trick to inherit the parent's prototype whilst not executing the parent's constructor:

```
var Parent = function () { ... };
var Child = function () {
  Parent.call(this);
  ...
};

var Fn = function () {};
Fn.prototype = Parent.prototype;
Child.prototype = new Fn();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, I'll try it out.  I expect the hasOwnProperty method doesn't work either when the chain is broken.  Can you think of anything else?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is inherited from `Object` so it does work. But `Parent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new Child()) === false`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code will run for you and allows access to the prototype. It involves making the parent an object literal and you can call a prototype method in your child's "constructor"

```
var Parent = {
    testMethod1 : function() {
        alert('testMethod1');
    }
}

Parent.testMethod2 = function() {alert('testMethod2');}

Child.prototype = Parent;
//Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
function Child()
{
    alert('im ready');
    Child.prototype.testMethod1();  
}


var child1 = new Child();
child1.testMethod1();
child1.testMethod2();

Parent.testMethod3 = function() {alert('testMethod3');}
child1.testMethod3();
```

and if you wanted to do away with 'new' you could use Object.create()

```
var Parent = {
    testMethod1 : function() {
        alert('testMethod1');
    }
}

Parent.testMethod2 = function() {alert('testMethod2');}

var child1 = Object.create(Parent);
child1.testMethod1();
child1.testMethod2();

Parent.testMethod3 = function() {alert('testMethod3');}
child1.testMethod3();

Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
```

In the second case you would need to call a function as your "constructor" after you create()'d the object, but it's true protototypal inheritance.

Comment: That works, but I lose the ability to create different Parent instances.  There are cases where I want to create multiple Parent objects.

Comment: see Object.create() in my revised answer.

Comment: That's closer but now I've lost the child constructor (and testMethod2, for example).  Also, it won't execute code on creation, which is something I need to do.

Comment: If you really want to use constructors than this coding style will not work for you... but you shouldn't have lost testMethod2. I just rechecked it in a jsfiddle and it works for me.

Comment: You're right; I mis-read your code, testMethod2 is there, but it's now a method of Parent.  In the fiddle example its a method of Child. I think probably what you want to do is child1.testMethod2 = function() {alert('testMethod2');}.  This is definitely a more "javascripty" prototypal approach.

Comment: In the fiddle testMethod2 is added as a function on the prototype of Parent like this Parent.prototype.testMethod2 = function() {alert('testMethod2');} A child1 function would be as you just described.